# SharpSSH shell thread dies on Read()

Tags: c#, ssh, sharpssh

I'm attempted to use SharpSSH's SSHShell class, but the thread dies somewhere in the stream on a read when the buffer is empty. Looks like they use PipeInputStream for the stream.

I'm calling the read and write from same thread. That might be the problem. I'm wondering if there is an easy remedy that someone knows about for this issue. I'm limited by existing framework we have in creating new threads on each side.  Everything works perfect until the last read on the empty buffer.

Thanks

Dean

Comment: Switched the lib to rebex and works fine in same situation. I guess I'm not a big fan of SharpSSH at this point.

Comment: I guess Open Source versus $349 per developer makes a difference in quality?

Comment: SharpSSH has not been updated since 2007. Avoid it.